# How to sort the array in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9

I have a following array

```
arr = ["2014-05-02T19-49-55_1280x720_vga2usb.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_544x288_left_cam.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_544x288_right_cam.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_1632x288.mp4"]
```

I need to sort this array in a way that I get following:

```
["2014-05-02T19-49-55_1632x288.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_544x288_left_cam.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_544x288_right_cam.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_1280x720_vga2usb.mp4"]
```

I tried to use the sort method `arr.sort`  and `arr.sort_by{|word| word.downcase}`
But it is giving me output as

```
["2014-05-02T19-49-55_1280x720_vga2usb.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_1632x288.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_544x288_left_cam.mp4", "2014-05-02T19-49-55_544x288_right_cam.mp4"]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please close question, if answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use sort like this:

```
arr.sort { |x,y| y <=> x }
```

If you need to sort by substring try something like this:

```
arr.sort { |x,y| y[m,n] <=> x[m,n]}
```

EDIT: this should work:

```
arr.sort do |x,y| 
    regex = /x[[:digit:]]+(.+?)$/
    regex.match(x)[1] <=> regex.match(y)[1]
end
```

Comment: You can shorten it to `arr.sort_by { |x| x[/x[[:digit:]]+(.+?)$/, 1] }`